# Balanced to unbalanced circuit not working correctly?

Tags: operational-amplifier, converter, balanced, unbalanced

I've tried to build a balanced to unbalanced signal converter with an TL072. The problem is that if I put a balanced sine signal into it I only get the bottom half of the sine as unbalanced signal out of the circuit. That’s not how it should work.
The circuit I am using is this circuit:
[image]
Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The problem was, I was using +30V but because in this schematic the OP-Amp is used in differential mode it requires +/-15V.

Comment: Do you have a 2 sided supply voltage for the op-amps?

Comment: Also, why are you using 2 op amps instead of 1? A differential amplifier implemented with an op amp solves the "larger" problem of converting a differential signal into one referred to a reference voltage (which could be ground with the appropriate configuration).

Comment: Most likely the other half lies outside the supply voltage range you are using. But we can't tell from the incomplete schematic.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had now the time to try it and using +/-15V it's working perfectly.